# 404 when submit() form by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms

In wordpress I created page with custom php code which will process posted data. When I open directly my custom page, for example http://example.com/page/ everything works. But when I use that page as form action, then I have error `Oops! That page can’t be found.`

```
<form id="orderForm" method="post" action="http://example.com/page/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="1" />
</form>
```

Error is when I run `$('#orderForm').submit();` directly in console or inside .on("click") event.

I tried:

- change action to "/page/"
- add `header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");`
- add header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

I got that error:
[image]

When I open page directly, everything works ok.

Comment: I might be wrong, but did you tried without the last `/` ?

`http://example.com/page/` could lead to look after the page `` under `/page` in the host `example.com`

So `http://example.com/page` is a call to `/page` in the hosts `example.com`

Comment: `page` is a folder or a file?  if you add the `/` at the end it will try to look inside folder `page` maybe for an index file (check the types of files that your server use as index...) if it's a file then delete the `/` and probably you'll need to add the extension... like page.php

Comment: "page" is wordpress subpage. I tried without /. When I put direct on browser `example.com/page` it redirect to `example.com/page/` but when I .submit() it doesnt. I tried `example.com/?p=100` but the same :/

Comment: Ok, what I observed: when I `$('#orderForm').submit();` when form is clear - it works. Problem is when I fill any input.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found problem! One of my input field had name and id = "name" ... I noticed that when I send form without this field, everything works. I changed input name to other and IT WORKS!

Anyone knows why I cant name input `name`? Is it some bug?

Thank you all for your commitment.

Comment: This might be one of WP quirky behaviours but most certainly you can name your inputs `name`. Now don't go on naming them `submit` (in JS all form elements are stored within form[`name`] object, overwriting any other attributes, such as for example submit function)

Comment: I also faced the same problem. if form has a input field with name "name" it returns 404

Answer (score 0):

The reason it didn't work is because Wordpress has a list of reserved variable names you can't use - 'name' is one of them!

https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms

Answer (score -2):

From what I understand, with .htaccess, the .php extension is hidden. So the full link is http://example.com/page.php instead. Use that